# Java: Using Kerberos LoginModule with JAAS

Tags: java, configuration, kerberos, aix, jaas

I have an application attempting to use the Kerberos LoginModule.  It appears that my problem is that the LoginModule being used is the wrong one.  I get the following error:

```
javax.security.auth.login.loginException: unable to find LoginModule class: com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule
```

Except this is on an AIX system, so I would expect it to be using com.**ibm**.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.  I can't figure out exactly where to specify this.  This is my first real foray into JAAS so I'm not familiar with all the settings and configuration, but it appears that the following entry in my java.security file in JAVA_HOME/lib/security should fix this:

```
login.configuration.provider=com.ibm.security.auth.login.ConfigFile
```

The only other issue is that there are approximately 12 different java installations on this machine, so I'm only *relatively* certain that I've got the right java.security file.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  I'm currently trying to pin down the configuration that is installed using javax.security.auth.login
.Configuration, but I figured in the meantime I'd post this; maybe someone has some information that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the Java Home was actually wrong.